# YouTube app full screen cropped by navigation and notification bars persisting on screen

Tags: notification-bar, youtube, navigation-bar, tinted-status-bar

For whatever reason, Google thinks that it makes sense to bring out the navigation and notification bars along with the intrusive annotation that cannot be manually dismissed, then leave the bars there dimmed to black for the remainder of the video covering up a portion of the frame.

This usually occurs when there is some annotation that appears.

[image]

My question is, how can these bars be removed?

Comment: Do you want to remove annotations? so that the bar doesn't appear or what?

Comment: @Matt07211 he wants to hide the notification & navigation bar again. Sometimes this issue happen (I have faced it), and it's not trivial to hide those again.

Comment: Pull down your notification bar down and drag out up again. This would hide the notification bar fully. It happens to me and this is how I hide it. What is your phone model and Android version.?